# How to encourage a hamster to chew more?

Tags: health, hamsters, chewing, dental-care

I have had a few hamsters over the years, but the hamster that I have now seems to not chew on its chew toys. I know that hamsters need to chew on things to prevent their teeth from growing too long which is why I am worried about my hamster not chewing. Is there anything I can do to help encourage a hamster to chew more?

Comment: first you should see a vet. The vet should look if there is anything with the mouth or teeth that prevent the hamster from chewing. maybe it is painfull for him.